# R shiny sliderInput show time

Tags: r, time, shiny

I have a question related to the sliderInput in R shiny.
In the sliderInput, the value is a number. Some examples show that the number is $number. However, if I want to show the value of sliderInput as a time, say 10:00, 15:00, how should I do it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, giving you some pointers that anyone with some JS knowledge can use. To the best of my knowledge, as of Shiny-0.5, you can achieve this only by writing some Javascript/JQuery.

If you are able to incorporate JQuery plug-ins into your UI.R Shiny app, [this link](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/stable/demo/) has what you want.

1. Use CSS style to make sure that the `SliderInput` labels get formatted the way you want. (Showing Date/Time as opposed to numbers.) I typically put any `tags$head()` styling code inside `SideBarPanel()` and it has worked.
2. You will also need a Javascript function that takes in the `input$number` and returns a valid date/time. **Link with code:** [This JQuery post](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-slider-for-date-range-in-two-text-boxes) has a javascript function that you should be able use (with DatePicker)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks very much. It sounds complex to you. Do you have some sample code to do this? Thanks a lot.