# Date Sliders in Shiny 0.11

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Making an `sliderInput` in `shiny::` for a date range has not been easy.  Before 0.11, it was sort-of possible to do it by hacking the javascript.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330025/sliderinput-for-date) for info.

Shiny 0.11 changed the javascript used for sliders.  The new `sliderInput` input is really pretty.  Nice job Rstudio!

But the old javascript hack no longer works :(

The new slider is supposed to have new formatting options, but if those options include a date range they aren't documented (yet).

Does anyone know how to do it?  If it can't be done natively, can someone suggest a way to do a javascript hack?

The example shiny app is here:  https://amose.shinyapps.io/shinyyieldcurve/, with the old javascript hack that sort-of mostly works most of the time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is an old question, and the link above doesn't work anymore.  Never got answered though :(