# Using dates with the ion.RangeSlider sliderInput in Shiny

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, slider, shiny, rangeslider

How can we use dates with `sliderInput` in Shiny?

I know it has been [difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330025/sliderinput-for-date) with Bootstrap 2.0, but now that Shiny is using the ion slider, there is hope:

According to the [documentation](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html),

> Slider supports date and time

For now, something like

`sliderInput("date",label="date",
             min=as.Date("1934-06-29"), max=as.Date("1940-03-04"))`

is still a dream.

I've [found](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo_advanced.html) some Javascript that seems to be relevant, but I'm not sure hot to implement this in the UI. Has anyone who knows Javascript incorportated this into any Shiny apps yet?

```
$("#range_39").ionRangeSlider({
    min: +moment().subtract(1, "years").format("X"),
    max: +moment().format("X"),
    from: +moment().subtract(6, "months").format("X"),
    prettify: function (num) {
        return moment(num, "X").format("LL");
    }
});
```

Thanks for reading this far.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Winston very recently added support for dates to the rangeslider, but it just hasn't been incorporated into shiny yet.

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/885

It should probably be finalized soon